# What does `-r dotenv/config` serve for?

Tags: webpack, package.json, dotenv

I know that it relates to `.env` file, but what actually it does in this build task?

```
"build:dev": "webpack-dev-server -r dotenv/config --open --config webpack.dev.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here: https://zetcode.com/javascript/dotenv/

`-r dotenv/config` is a command line which serves for preloading `dotenv` and its `config()` method. `-r` is equivalent to `--require`. If we do not use it in a command line, then we need to require `dotenv` in our application like this: `require('dotenv').config()`